# Indexing of Same Values in a List

Tags: python, list

Due to `list.index(x)` will only return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. Is there any way to return every index of same values in the list.

For example, I have a list containing some same values like:

```
mylist = [(A,8), (A,3), (A,3), (A,3)]
```

I want to return:

```
index_of_A_3 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
mylist = [(A,8), (A,3), (A,3), (A,3)]
def indices( mylist, value):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x==value]

print indices(mylist, (A,3))
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain more about enumerate().

Comment: `enumerate` takes a single iterable as an argument and returns a new iterator, whose values are tuples of an index and an element from the original iterable. An example speaks volumes: `list(enumerate(["foo", "bar", "baz"])) == [(0,"foo"), (1, "bar"), (2, "baz")]`.

Comment: Thanks both of you, Brent Newey and katrielatex.

Answer (score 2):

Replace (A,3) with what you want or use a lambda.

```
[i for i in range(len(mylist)) if mylist[i]==(A,3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda ugly but:

```
index_of_A_3 = [i for i in range(len(mylist)) if mylist[i] == (A,3)]
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is exactly the same as Kabie's.

Answer (score 0):

more quickly !!!!

```
index_of_A_3= np.where(mylist == (A,3))[0]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.